# Relation Conditions with Variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have the following models:

```
class Publication < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :reviews
  has_many :users, :through => :owned_publications
  has_many :owned_publications
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :publications, :through => :owned_publications
  has_many :owned_publications
end

class OwnedPublication < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :publication
  belongs_to :user
  has_one :review, :conditions => "user_id = #{self.user.id} AND publication_id = #{self.publication.id}"
end
```

In the third model, I'm trying to set a condition with a pair of variables. It seems like the syntax works, except that self is not an instance of OwnedPublication. Is it possible to get the current instance of OwnedPublication and place it into a condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your best bet is to just have the Review record belong_to an OwnedPublication, and setup your Publication model to get the reviews via a method:

```
def reviews
  review_objects = [] 
  owned_publications.each do |op|
    review_objects << op
  end
  review_objects
end
```

Might be a more efficient way if you use a subquery to get the information, but it removes the concept of having unnecessary associations.

Comment: This works. For future reference, do you know if there is a way to get the current instance of a model within an association's condition?

Comment: I have to admit that I haven't used the condition option. Based on the details in the api docs, the conditions essentially accepts a SQL where clause. So you would either have to specify the tablename.field, or just the field name and the condition.

Answer (score 4):

The solution requires the use of :through and :source options, as well as a proc call:

```
has_one :review, :through => :publication, :source => :reviews,
  :conditions => proc { ["user_id = ?", self.user_id] }
```

Proc is the trick to passing in dynamic variables to ActiveRecord association conditions, at least as of Rails 3.0. Simply calling:

```
has_one :conditions => proc { ["publication_id = ? AND user_id = ?",
  self.publication_id, self.user_id] }
```

will not work, though. This is because the association will end up searching the reviews table for a 'reviews.owned_publication_id' column, which does not exist. Instead, you can find the proper review through publication, using publication's :reviews association as the source.

Comment: You are the man! Not sure about how it works but I could get to that later!